# Distribution with density $x^2\operatorname{exp}\{-x^2/2\}$

Tags: reference-request, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I came across the probability distribution with density
$$
f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\,x^2\,\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{2}},\quad x\geqslant 0.
$$

Is this distribution known under a certain name? I only found references to general polynomial-normal densities, such as [here](http://people.stat.sfu.ca/~tim/papers/poly.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: [the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) with $$a=\sqrt{\frac{kT}{m}}=1,$$
where $m$ is the particle mass and $kT$ is the product of Boltzmann's constant and thermodynamic temperature.

(The pdf in question describes the speed distribution of particles in idealised gases.)